# Unable to check Turtlebot Cable

Tags: usb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,
when I try to run

> roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch

this is error appear :
Failed to open port /dev/ttyUSB0.  Please make sure the Create cable is plugged into the computer.

we try to solve this problem ,we search alot in the Community
So, we add this
ATTRS{idProduct}=="2303",ATTRS{idVendor}=="067b",MODE="666",GROUP="turtlebot"

in this file :/etc/udev/rules.d/52-turtlebot.rules

this file created filesystem/dev/ttyUSB0
after :

> roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch

But after :

> roslaunch turtlebot_navigation gmapping_demo.launc
> this file created :filesystem/dev/ttyUSB1
> and USB0 disappear
> and this error  appear again
> unable to check cable.

,I'm using fuerte on ubuntu 11.10.

Any help??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57553/unable-to-check--turtlebot-cable/) by [howyda](https://answers.ros.org/users/3699/howyda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2013-03-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a set of instructions you need to follow:

1.Check that initially no USB is connected to the system

2.First USB connected to your system should be Turtlebot cable, which will occupy the ttyUSB0 position

3.'After reading your above problem', you need to provide root rights to your USB0 port, using the command "sudo chmod 0777 /dev/ttyUSB0"

4.Now run roscore and check if the problem still exists.

---

Originally posted by [sudhanshu_mittal](https://answers.ros.org/users/5307/sudhanshu_mittal/) with karma: 311 on 2013-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0